# Getting the selected radio button index in Struts

Tags: jsp, struts, javabeans, struts-1, apache-commons-beanutils

I have some radio buttons on a Struts 1 form.

```
<input type="radio" name="productId" value="31415" />
<input type="radio" name="productId" value="31416" />
```

Then in the Action class I can get the values from the form just fine. For example if I select the first radio button then `myForm.getProductId()` returns 31415.

The question is, is there a way in Struts 1 to tell which input field was selected by index with keeping the current functionality?

(In *worst case* I know that I can create a new hidden field that contains the selected radio button and update that field from JavaScript, but I would like to avoid that way as well.)

**Explanation:**
The radio buttons are created based on a collection, but for some reason the collection's elements sometimes don't have a product ID, so if there are multiple elements like that, then I can't tell which radio button was selected. But I'd like to know even in those cases, to improve the fault tolerance of the system.
(I have no power over the elements of the collection, it comes from a web service.)

Comment: There isn't. Knowing which position the radio is in is pretty irrelevant in 99.9% of cases. Where do the values for those productId radio buttons come from? If it's some sort of collection that you have in Java then you could find the index pretty easily.

Comment: What is the selected index, do you mean a tabulated index?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I added a little explanation to the question

Comment: @RomanC I mean their position in the form, counting only radio buttons.

Comment: Does the form have other input elements?

Comment: Yes, there are other input fields as well. But the radio buttons continuously follow each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can use indexed properties for the indexed name of the input fields.

> For indexed properties, `BeanUtils.populate()`
>   uses the name of the request parameter to determine the proper setter method to call on the `ActionForm`

Use indexed names

```
<input type="radio" name="productId[0]" value="31415" />
<input type="radio" name="productId[1]" value="31416" />
```

Define indexed properties

```
private String[] productId;

public String getProductId(int index) {
  return productId[index];
}
public void setProductId(int index, String productId) {
  productId[index] = productId;
}
public String[] getProductId( ) {
  return productId;
}
```

Comment: I think this breaks the current functionality, but... how can I tell which radio button was selected with this? Will the string array only have value at one position? Like [null, null, "1", null]? If the radio button has no value set will I get an empty string in the array?

Comment: You can get the value by the index that is provided to the setter method.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have to take this one back. As it turned out, this breaks the radio button functionality. Not having the same name they will start to act as independent radio button groups. https://jsfiddle.net/qkv486nb/1/